# To run Makefile.tpl in OSX

Tags: macos, compile, c

I have the file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Makefile.tpl) which syntax seems to be near normal make-file with parameter **install**.

I run unsuccessfully

```
make install
```

I get

```
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

I get the same errors also with the command **gnumake** in OSX.

**How can you run the *Makefile.tpl* in OSX?**

I get this to Jeremy's command

```
wave$ sudo make -f Makefile.tpl install
mkdir -p /help/wave;  /help/wave
/bin/sh: /help/wave: is a directory
make: *** [/help/wave] Error 126
```

so not working for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `make -f Makefile.tpl install`.

Make defaults to using `Makefile` and `makefile`, and won't realize that `Makefile.tpl` is the file you want it to take rules from unless you tell it with the `-f` option.

In general, though, a *.tpl file is going to be a template. I'd expect some sort of configure step to expand the template for your specific system and generate a `Makefile` (no .tpl suffix) as a result.

Comment: I added the output after running your command. It gives me error 126. What does it mean in OSX case?

Comment: @Masi: That is how you run Makefile.tpl. The problem is, you don't really want to run Makefile.tpl. The error you're getting is because SETDPERMISSIONS is empty, so it tries to run a directory as a command and errors out. Please follow the instructions at http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb-darwin-quick-start.shtml, including to run `./configure` before `sudo make install`.